# Setting readline variables in the shell

Tags: bash, readline

I read in the `man` page, that you set readline parameters on an off or to a value by using

```
set var value
```

Is this the same as the `set` builtin, and how do you set the variables once `inputrc` has already been read and the shell is running?

Comment: And, a note for the record, the readline `set` is *not* the same as the shell builtin `set`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `set` command in the readline manual is the one in readline's configuration file, `~/.inputrc`. Although bash is the most famous user of the readline library, the library is generic and can be used by other programs; the syntax of `.inputrc` is unrelated to bash.

You can make bash execute readline commands through the `bind` builtin:

```
bind "set var value"
```

Also, you can make bash reread `~/.inputrc` with `bind -f ~/.inputrc`.

Answer (score 5):

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File.html):

> When a program which uses the Readline library starts up, the init file is read, and the key bindings are set.
> In addition, the <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> command re-reads this init file<sup>1</sup>, thus incorporating any changes that you might have made to it.

<sup>1</sup> **Note** this is obviously the Emacs (default) binding, if you use `editing-mode-vi` there is no default keybind. However, you can bind the `re-read-init-file` command to a keybind of your choice in `~/.inputrc`.